# Differential Backup with Scheduling, Manual Naming, Browsing, Cleanup

Tags: windows-7, backup, software-rec, disk-image

I'm looking for a local disk image / disaster recovery backup solution for Windows 7 that can do the following...

1. Schedule a full disk image once every 3 months
2. Schedule a weekly differential image from the most recent full image
3. Perform a manual backup with a custom name, label, or description
4. Supports and backs up multiple partitions on disk
5. Recover individual files by browsing an image like a disk drive
6. Automatically make space for newly scheduled images by intelligently deleting old ones
7. Perform a bare bones recovery from any image (same hardware)
8. Bonus Points: Fast, Simple/Clean Interface, Bloat-Free

It's so difficult to get specific questions like these answered without installing and trying everything that's out there! Have any of you guys seen anything that comes close? Willing to pay for it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[ShadowProtect](http://www.storagecraft.com/shadow_protect_desktop.php). Excellent Software; we use it across hundreds of servers with awesome results. You can mount your backups like disks and restore backups to a totally different machine!

I've heard good things about [acronis](http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/products/trueimage/index.html) too, but haven't used it.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the heads up on ShadowProtect! It looks a little more complicated (professional?) than what I was hoping for, but I'll definitely keep it in mind while I search for alternatives. It hits a lot of the points I mentioned above. Acronis is a bit too bloated for my tastes.

Comment: @calbar it's actually really simple to use. Give it a try, the trial is a full one(well almost)